# How can I use UIlabel.text in other controller?

Tags: swift

I have two Controller which is Map and BottomSheet.
Once i click marker in Map I want to change UIlabel text.

BottomsheetController.swift

```
var Data : [DataClass] = []

class BottomSheetViewController : UIViewController{


@IBOutlet weak var Id: UILabel!

func getid(id : String?){
    let kick = id
    self.Id.text = kick
    }
}
```

MapViewController.swift

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController ,GMUClusterManagerDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    addBottomSheetView()
}


// MARK: Click marker
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    if let poiitem = marker.userData as? POIItem {
            let bvc = BottomSheetViewController()
            bvc.getimei(imei: Data[0].id)

         }
         return true
    }
}
```

it keeps saying Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: `mvc.getimei()` in `mapView()` did error occur? I'm not sure, but I think `Data[0].id` is nil value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use segue for passing data between two controller

performSegue(idnitfierName,sender)

And than,

perform(){

let vc = segue.destination as! MapViewController
vc.variableName = variable That you have to pass

}

Comment: What do I have to do if I use xib not storyboard?